# Issue using the Wordpress REST API with Python

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

I am currently using the Wordpress API in order to post articles in my test website. As I'm quite new to this, I followed this tutorial : https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/wordpress-rest-api-with-python-f53a25827b1c (using Application Passwords to access the API)

My issue is that when I write my url as follows in my Python script :

- url = "https://my-website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts" I get <Response [401]> (incorrect password)
- and when my url is simply "https://my-website.com" I get <Response [200]> (no error but nothing is posted on the website)

It seems like I have an authentication issue when trying to access the Wordpress REST API but I can't find any other issues like this one.

Thank you !

(PS : just precising that my website is hosted on Kinsta, i don't know if it has something to do with it?)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently and found I needed to edit my Bitnami instance's Apache `httpd-app.conf` config settings by inserting the following line inside the `<Directory>` tags:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

[Source](https://community.bitnami.com/t/setting-up-api-access-to-wordpress-on-aws-ec2-instance/60589/9)

Answer (score -1):

Try to change this

```
header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8')}
```

with

```
header = {"Authorization": "Basic " + token.decode("utf-8")}
```

Single quotation marks can be confusing because they can also be in token.decode